# JSON.NET deserialize JSON object stored as property

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have a JSON message to deserialize with a string property containing the JSON of another object. I have the following classes

```
public class Envelope
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public Message InnerMessage { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

the JSON message I receive is in this format:

```
{
    Type : "send",
    InnerMessage : "{ From: \"sender\", To: \"receiver\", Body: \"test\" }"
}
```

note that `InnerMessage` contains the serialization of the `Message` class, not the JSON of the class.

If I keep the type of `InnerMessage` property to `Message`, the standard JSON.NET deserialization fails.

If I change the `InnerMessage` to `string`, the serialization works but after I need to deserialize again the content of `InnerMessage` to `Message` class:

```
Envelope envelope = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Envelope>(jsonMessage);
Message innerMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Envelope>(envelope.InnerMessage);
```

There is some way to keep the `InnerMessage` property of `Envelope` to `Message` and tell JSON.NET to treat the string value to be deserialized automatically?

Comment: How are you serializing your object? When I use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(envelope)` I get different Json output than you.

Comment: I get the JSON from a webservice, I just need to deserialize it to the classes I created

Comment: Gotcha, looks like @SirRufo has the answer your looking for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a custom `JsonConverter`

```
class StringTypeConverter : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanRead => true;
    public override bool CanWrite => true;

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        string json = (string)reader.Value;
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, objectType);
        return result;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, json);
    }
}
```

and add a `JsonConverterAttribute` to the `InnerMessage` property

```
public class Envelope
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter(typeof(StringTypeConverter))]
    public Message InnerMessage { get; set; }
}

public class Message
{
    public string From { get; set; }
    public string To { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

and now you can serialize/deserialize the `Envelope` class with

```
var envelope = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Envelope>( jsonMessage );
```

Comment: thanks, your solution looks cleaner than the other one, tomorrow I will test it

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a custom converter. For example:

```
public class EnvelopeConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, 
        JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, 
        object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var envelope = JObject.Load(reader);

        var type = envelope["Type"].ToString();
        var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Message>(
            envelope["InnerMessage"].ToString());

        return new Envelope
        {
            Type = type,
            InnerMessage = message
        };
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
Envelope envelope = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Envelope>(
    jsonMessage, new EnvelopeConverter());
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but personally I prefer the one of Sir Rufo as I can apply to the specific property and not to the class